Reflected Field getAnnotation returns null in mvn test but fine in intelliJ
EDIT : To generate sonar report, we use jacoco. For reasons I don't understand yet, Jacoco added a "synthetic" field $jacocoData to my Foo class during compile time when I run mvn clean test. It doesnt when I start debugging the test with IntelliJ. This field doesnt have my custom defined Bar annotation (since it isn't defined by programmer), causing the exception. I wasn't aware of that behaviour from JaCoCo, or the concept of synthetic fields.
Solution is to filter the synthetic fields after getDeclaredFields() with Field.isSynthetic() method.
I have a custom annotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Foo {
    String value() default "";
}

I use it on every fields of an object
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Bar implements Serializable {
    @Foo(value = "Wololo")
    private String aaa;
}

When I try to read the annotation in a test class, I get a null pointer exception
 for (Field field : Bar.class.getDeclaredFields())
 {
     field.setAccessible(true);
     Foo annotation = field.getAnnotation(Foo.class);
     String value = annotation.value(); // Null Exception
 }

But it only happens when I run mvn test. If I skip test in maven surefire plugin config and run the test in debug mode (IntelliJ using mvn install), I have no issue.
I am using Maven 3.9.6, surefire 3.2.1, junit 5.9.2, java 8
Am I missing something ?

How do I mark a question as self-answered ?

By not inserting the answer into your question but posting an actual answer (see below). Then, after some time, you can mark your answer as accepted. By the way, there is no need to call setAccessible(true) for reading the annotation of a field. Further note that the point of the special name “value” for an annotation value is that you can omit the name then, i.e. @Foo("Wololo").
